# setInterval in IONIC 3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I would like to run a function in every 1 second. After searching, I found `setInterval` but it doesn't work for me.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   this.myfuntion();

}, 1000);
```

I also tried `this.myfuntion` but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 13):

The solution is to use **[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**:

```
setInterval(() => { 
   this.myfuntion(); // Now the "this" still references the component
}, 1000);
```

When using **arrow functions**, the `this` property is not overwritten and still references the component instance.

Answer (score 9):

There are Basically two methods to perform that.

Try using observable which will suit best your requirement.

**Method 1:**

```
import {Observable} from 'Rxjs/rx';
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

// if you want your code to work everytime even though you leave the page
Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(()=>{
    this.functionYouWantToCall();
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
// if you want your code to work only for this page
//define this before constructor
observableVar: Subscription;

this.observableVar = Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(()=>{
    this.functionYouWantToCall();
});

ionViewDidLeave(){
   this.observableVar.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: This function will work when application is in background ?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone struggling with this, you can use *interval* from *rxjs* like the following :

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
  this.myfuntion();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. I think it's a scope issue. without binding the scope in setInterval goes to the window object

```
      setInterval(function(){ this.myfunction();}.bind(this), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used it like this:

```
import {interval, Subscription} from 'rxjs';

  const source = interval(30000);
        this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => {
          // TODO
        });
```

you can use it inside the constructor or inside a function and then call it from outside.